# Regress one variable on all of the others

Tags: sas, regression

I have a SAS data set with hundreds of variables.  I want to take the tenth variable and regress it on all of the others, something like

```
   proc reg data=mydata;
      model [10th one] = [all the others];
   run;
```

Is there a simple way to do this without typing out the complete variable list?  I can imagine a horribly tedious solution in which I (a) look up the 10th variable name and enter that one manually on the left-hand side and (b) use an sql statement to put all the other variables in a macro variable for the right-hand side.

Comment: Do your variables have a naming convention at all? If so, can possibly use shorthand notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplification of your method, using `dictionary.columns`.  This is completely identical to the `proc contents` method in what ultimately happens, it just makes it take a bit less code and a bit less time.

```
proc sql;
  select name into :reg_varlist separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname='WORK' and memname='MYDAT'
      and name ne "&tenth_Variable";
quit;

proc reg data=mydat;
   model &tenth_variable = &reg_varlist;
run;
```

You could trivially wrap that in a macro if you wanted, with `tenth_variable` as a parameter.

If you actually want to regress the "tenth variable" specifically, and don't care what it's called, then you can use `varnum`.

Here is a macro that does this in a basic form. The regression modeled below probably is entirely nonsensical, and this makes no effort to protect from character variables being selected and such; you probably would want to add that in (`and type="num"` for example).

```
%macro regress_onevar(varnum=,dataset=,libname=work);
    proc sql;
      select name into :reg_varlist separated by ' '
        from dictionary.columns
        where libname=upcase("&libname.") and memname=upcase("&dataset.")
          and varnum ne &varnum.;    *varnum=position in dataset;

      select name into :tenth_variable
        from dictionary.columns
        where libname=upcase("&libname.") and memname=upcase("&dataset.")
          and varnum eq &varnum.;
     quit;

    proc reg data=&libname..&dataset.;
       model &tenth_variable = &reg_varlist;
    run;
%mend regress_onevar;

%regress_onevar(varnum=10,dataset=usecon,libname=sashelp);
```

Comment: The first half is essentially the same as Reese's second half, which either was edited in after I first read it or I just missed; `dictionary.columns` and `sashelp.vcolumn` are both views of the same data (the former only available in `PROC SQL`, the latter available anywhere).

Comment: No problem, that happens - just wanted to make sure it was clear that I wasn't suggesting something (very) different in that part

Answer (score 3):

Lets say that you know the following variables:
1st - Var_1st
9th - Var_9th
11th - Var_11th
Nth - Var120th

```
proc reg data=mydata;
  model [10th one] = var_1st--var_9th var_11th--var_120th;
run;quit;
```

If you fully want to automate use sashelp.vcolumn:

```
proc sql noprint;
select name into :reg_list separated by " " from sashelp.vcolumn where upper(libname)='WORK' and    upper(memname)='MYDATA' and varnum ne 10;
select name into :dep_list from sashelp.vcolumn where upper(libname)='WORK' and upper(memname)='MYDATA' and varnum eq 10;
quit;

proc reg data=mydata;
model &dep_list = &reg_list;
run;quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best thing I've found so far, which presumes that you're not too lazy to look up the name of the 10th variable:

```
proc contents data=mydat(drop=[name of 10th variable]) out=varnames(keep=name) noprint; 
run;
proc sql noprint;
   select name into : reg_varlist separated by ' '
   from varnames;
quit;
run;

proc reg data=mydat;
   model [name of 10th variable]) = &reg_varlist;
run;
```